# How to mount a zfs poolfile with dataset as a loopback?

Tags: 22.04, zfs

I have a installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 (from `22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`), running at VirtualBox 7, with installed `zfs-tools`.

I have an image file from a zfs pool called `zfsfile01`.
I can look in this file with:

```
fdisk -l zfsfile01
```

and I get the value with 2 datasets: `dataset01` and `dataset02` - the file seems to be ok.

Now I have to mount the file `zfsfile01` itself or the second `dataset02` as a loopback device.
After reading some useful texts, I recognized that I have to first import the poolfile with `zpool` and then mount a filesystem (a dataset?) from the poolfile with `zfs mount`. Importing the pool with

```
zpool import <pathto>/zfsfile01
```

failed with:

```
cannot import <pathto>/zfsfile01: no such pool available
```

I guess because of the file and no right zfs pool.

Basically, I can go on with the `mount` command in Linux and can mount a dumped file with `sudo mount -o loop,offset=xxx image.dd /tmp/destination` and such stuff. But I don't know which options I have to use to mount a zfs pool file with dataset as a loop back device.

Here is the output of `sudo fdisk -l zfsfile01`: *(response to comment)*

```
Festplatte ewf1: 1,82 TiB, 2000398934016 Bytes, 3907029168 Sektoren
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 44E0E83D-A9CA-11EC-xxxx-xxxxx
Gerät       Anfang       Ende       Sektoren   Größe Typ
dataset1    128          4194431    4194304    2G FreeBSD Swap
dataset2    4194432      3907029127 3902834696 1,8T FreeBSD ZFS
```

Here is the output of `losetup`: *(response to Artur's answer)*

```
$ losetup -f
/dev/loop8
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop8 /media/sf_E_DRIVE/zfsfile01
losetup: /media/sf_E_DRIVE/zfsfile01: Loop-Gerät konnte nicht eingerichtet werden: Vorgang nicht zulässig
```

I can loop a `dd` image with:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop8 /media/image.dd
```

and then I can un-loop the device with:

```
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop8
```

But I get an error with `zfsfile01`:

```
Loop-Gerät konnte nicht eingerichtet werden: Vorgang nicht zulässig
```

which means:

```
cannot setup loop-device: progress is not valid
```

Comment: I don't know what "imagefile from a zfs pool" means - but what is the name of the zpool? You should be able to do `zpool import <zpool-name>`.

Comment: @guiverc: Its a ubuntu 22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso on virtualbox 7.0

Comment: @artur meinild: i got a file with the size of 2 TB. the owner said to me: this is the image of a NAS-partition (how ever...) and this is a zfs pool with datasets in it. It seems to be ok so far, the fdisk -l zfsfile01 said, that the type is zfs and there are two datasets in it.

Comment: @artur meinild: no, sorry the zpool import <pathto>/zfsfile01 dont work. i got a error: "cannot import /zfsfile01: no such pool available"

Comment: Could you list the complete output of `fdisk -l zfsfile01` in your question? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like the image contains ZFS datasets, but rather that the "datasets" are actually partitions - where only partition 2 contains a Zpool. So you should probably find a way to only mount partition 2 from the file as a loopback, and then import the zpool from this partition.

Comment: Also please note that these are FreeBSD partitions, and not Linux partitions. This might be why it's not working out of the box.

Comment: Artur, i will ask with these insights a new question. Thanks a lot to you!

Comment: I went to forums.freebsd.org, if i have new insights, i will post these here. Alois.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [guide here](https://wiki.orzfly.com/topics/zfs-on-linux-mount-raw-pool-image), that hopefully is applicable to your case.

This is how I would translate it to your situation:

1. Mount image as loop device:

   ```
   # losetup /dev/loop100 /<pathto>/zfsfile01
   ```
2. Create partitions (only if the image contains partitions):

   ```
   # kpartx -av /dev/loop100
   add map loop100p1 (252:0): <something>
   add map loop100p9 (252:1): <something>
   ```
3. Create mount point:

   ```
   # mkdir /mnt/<poolname>
   ```
4. Try to import the ZFS pool with this pool name:

   ```
   # zpool import -R /mnt/<poolname> -d /dev/mapper
      pool: <poolname>
        id: <specific ID>
     state: ONLINE
    status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool.
    action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier, though
            some features will not be available without an explicit 'zpool upgrade'.
    config:

           <poolname>       ONLINE
             loop100        ONLINE
   ```
5. With the ID from previous result, you can import the pool with new options and name (if necessary - maybe you can skip this step and just use `<poolname>` in the following):

   ```
   # zpool import -o readonly=on -f -d /dev/mapper <specific ID> <new_poolname> -R /mnt/<poolname>
   ```
6. Done:

   ```
   # zpool status
     pool: <new_poolname>
    state: ONLINE
   status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
           still be used, but some features are unavailable.
   action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
           the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
           the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
     scan: none requested
   config:

           NAME             STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
           <new_poolname>   ONLINE       0     0     0
             loop100        ONLINE       0     0     0

   errors: No known data errors

   # zfs list <new_poolname> -r
   NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
   <new_poolname>             xxxM  xxxxG  xxK  /mnt/<poolname>
   <new_poolname>/dataset01   xxxM  xxxxG  xxK  /mnt/<poolname>/dataset01
   <new_poolname>/dataset02   xxxM  xxxxG  xxK  /mnt/<poolname>/dataset02
   ```